# referencing static JSON produced cli build --prod error

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

I have an angular 5 app that is loading a static JSON file via:

```
import * as config from '../../assets/config.json';
```

the imported file contains a JSON object ["xxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx"]with four strings in the object.

I have a line in the application that references the object which looks like:

```
const  URL = config[1];
```

When I run the app via ng serve it runs flawlessly. When I try to do a production build via

```
ng build --prod
```

I receive the following error which I have figured out is tied to the above line referencing config[1]:

```
ERROR in chunk main [initial]
[name].[chunkhash:20].bundle.js
The "string" argument must be of type string. Received type number
```

I am inferring from this error that I should either be declaring or referencing the value differently.  How should I change this so that it works as expected?

Comment: try `const config: string[] = require('../../assets/config.json');`? This is somehow the same but probably can work better with prod build

Comment: that solved it. Posting answer with your solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

smnbbrv's response solved the problem. Using require fixed the issue.